# Listing all installed apps on my Kivy App

Tags: android, ios, linux, windows, kivy

I need to list all the installed applications on an operating system like android or window etc. on my KIVY app, just like the list that we got in our app manager. So I need to write a program by which I can do so. Please Help.

How to list all installed applications on an operating system in my KIVY applications?

Comment: The answer varies by platform, but the answer for ios is "you cannot".

Comment: Can you give me for Android platform?